# vertical centering of Myriad Pro in IE9 and IE10

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9, vertical-alignment, internet-explorer-10

I've a single line of text written with Myriad Pro vertically centered to parent. In most browsers it renders fine, however in IE9&10 the text is not exactly centered, it shifted up by about 3 pixels from its correct position.

I've found out that the problem is caused by the font, the same case is rendered correctly with Arial. On the following image you can see the problem. Part of the text is selected and
it seems that the text is sticked to the top of the selection for some weird reason and the selection is vertically centered correctly.

[image: align problem]

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        div
          {
            vertical-align:middle;
            height:40px;
            line-height:40px;
            background-color:red;
            font-family:"Myriad pro",arial;
          }
      </style>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div>LOREM IPSUM</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please explain me why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this so that SO can reproduce your problem and play with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem using Adobe Typekit. Myriad Pro written with Typekit is correctly vertically centered.

But I still wonder why this happens.